# How to combine many faces into single face

Tags: modeling

I created a dice using a tutorial. When I export it I see that it has about 10000 faces. My problem is how to join all the faces of the dice, so it only has 6 faces in total, like a cube has. I want to add a function where the dice rolls and gives an outcome, so I am facing a problem to give numbers to the faces. Please suggest a way to combine the faces.

My dice link is http://www.sggame.bugs3.com/dice1.html

Comment: Sorry for bad English.I need answer to solve my problem.Thank you

Comment: You can try **`X` - Limited Dissolve**.

Comment: please make questions self-contained (a valid Q without external links)

Comment: limited dissolve not working

Comment: what i add for better result? @ ideasman42

Comment: Why not just use a cube? If you want a model with only 6 faces, there aren't many possibilities..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only 6 faces, then any detail on the faces will have to be represented using textures.  Fortunately, textures can be used to create several kinds of detail and I can think of the following off the top of my head being easy to do in webgl:

- color
- specular parameters (although you might have to use glsl)
- normal (affects specular and other kinds of lighting)

Blender also supports

- displacement
- mirror parameters

You probably want to research how to BAKE a texture from your high-res model into something usable in a 6-quad model.  A quick google search comes up with 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj-S5QAac3U about textures (which probably isn't useful in your case) and http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/baking-normal-maps-from-models.php which is for an ancient version of blender, but actually talks about baking from high-poly to low-poly.

Comment: OK, I finally found a modern tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7PQGgz1RII

Comment: i need to bake all 6 side of cube and combine them that's a better idea other than all. I need to know only that how to adjust the corner of the dice. because they are curvy in real and they will be seems curvy after bake but in actual the dice will be a cube with six plane only.